# a javascript code for returning a radio box value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a ajax table that I want to mark one of the rows in the table with radio box on the left , problem is that I'm not good at javascript , I want to get the radio box value by id from this table when it has marked , actually this ajax table shows info's from database by using while loop and an array . 
can anybody write a code for getting or returning informations of a selected row by radio box with javascript .

this is my ajax table :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
$db = mysql_select_db('students', $connection);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_persian_ci'"); 
$term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['searchit'],0, 100));
$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
if($term=="")
echo " .enter a usernumber";
else{
$query = mysql_query("select * from test where username like '{$term}%'", $connection);
$string = '';
echo "<br>";
                        echo "<center>";
                                echo "<div>";
                                    echo "<div align='center' width = 900>";
                                         echo "<table class='styled-table' cellspacing='0' width='900' border='1'>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Check</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Username</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Password</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Name</th>";    
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Last Name</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Midterm</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Class Mark</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Final</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>State</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Level</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Teacher</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Class Num</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Receipt</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Date</th>";
                                            echo "</tr>";



if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='checkbox' name='check' id='check' value= " . $row['check'] ."  ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='user' id='user' value= " . $row['username'] ." ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='pass' id='pass' value= " . $row['password'] ."  ></td>"; 
                                        ?>        <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='name' id='name' value= "<? echo $row['name']; ?>" ></td>
                                                  <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' value= "<? echo $row['lastname']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='midmark' id='midmark'  value= "<? echo $row['midmark']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='classmark' id='classmark'  value= "<? echo $row['classmark']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='finalmark' id='finalmark'  value= "<? echo $row['finalmark']; ?>"></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='state' id='state' value= "<? echo $row['state']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='level' id='level' value= "<? echo $row['level']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='teacher' id='teacher' value= "<? echo $row['teacher']; ?>" ></td>
                                        <?php   echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='classnum' id='classnum' value= " . $row['classnum'] ." ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='receipt' id='receipt' value= " . $row['receipt'] ." ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input'  type='text' name='date' id='date' value= " . $row['date'] ." ></td>";     
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        $_SESSION["suser"]=$row['username'] ;
                                        if(($row['check'])==true)
                                        {$_SESSION["sreceipt"]=$row['receipt'] ;}

                                        }
                                        echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</center>";


}else{
$string = "nothing found !";
$_SESSION["suser"]='';
$_SESSION["sreceipt"]='';
}

echo $string;
}
?>
```

Comment: Holy inline styles, Batman! Or do I mean _wholly_ inline styles?

Comment: sorry for that , I fixed it

Comment: Why echo out the html instead of just close the php block and have regular html? You do it for part of the file, but not all of it, generally the idea is to keep it consistent however you do it.

Comment: Be careful when using id attributes inside loops, right now you are generating repeating ids for your inputs, use classes instead; if you really need ids then append a unique value

Comment: rephrasing the question, "How do I extract the selected value of a radio button in a dynamically generated table using javascript?", you will find *many* answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get checked radio button value using AJAX in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145990/how-to-get-checked-radio-button-value-using-ajax-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://jsbin.com/iqicar/2

You can easily set up da "delegated event" that listens for checkbox change events inside the table. In the event handler, you can simply use jQuery to find the `<tr>` and then do all kinds of things - including grabbing all values from this row's input fields etc. and storing them somewhere (maybe via AJAX).

Note that I used jQuery UI in the jsbin only for the highlight effect :D

Comment: thanks @defaude this is what I want but instead of showing message I want to return a field value to another page . could you give me the code page !

Comment: Just go to the edit page of the JS Bin link: http://jsbin.com/iqicar/2/edit and take a look at the javascript code.

Instead of alerting stuff, you could use jQuery to traverse the row, collect values and send an AJAX request to the server.

Comment: I've seen it but the problem is I'm not good at javascript and jquery , in the code above of my ajax table I want to return reciept value of  selected row could you guid me with it ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iqicar/5 - If you know you're not (yet) good with the language JavaScript and/or the library jQuery... Then I suggest you read :D Crockford's "JavaScript - The good parts" is not too thick and very very good. jQuery has excellent api documentation.

Comment: that's amazing , this what I wanted , thanks for your advice too . my last request is how can I put that variable (in your code : recieptvalue ) in a php variable ? then with my code It will work and receipt value will send to another page and I can edit that row.

Comment: I've tested the code but I didn't get any result or a message box window ! I can not write the code in here I'm going to write the code in an answer .

Comment: Look at the comment from @koala_dev - you are creating html elements with duplicate id attributes - you really should remove those. And the code sample in my JSBin example is just an example, not the final product.
What do you mean with "highlight window"?

To get that value to your server (where the PHP is), you will need to send an AJAX request - but this is another topic and not in scope of this question.

Comment: how can I run this code you have written get to work on my page ? with this functions my problem is going to fix . but I can not  make it work as you can see in below .

Comment: I can't tell you what you need to do on your page in your code! Inspect the latest version of my JSBin and instead of popping out the value with `alert`, do *something* else with it. e.g. send it to the server via AJAX or whatever. Go read up on [jQuery's ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) if you want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>



<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
$db = mysql_select_db('students', $connection);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_persian_ci'"); 
$term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['searchit'],0, 100));
$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention

if($term=="")
echo " .enter user number ";
else{
$query = mysql_query("select * from test where username like '{$term}%'", $connection);
$string = '';
echo "<br>";
                        echo "<center>";
                                echo "<div>";
                                    echo "<div align='center' width = 900>";
                                         echo "<table class='styled-table' cellspacing='0' width='900' border='1'>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Check</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Username</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Password</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Name</th>";    
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Last Name</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Midterm</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Class Mark</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Final</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>State</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Level</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Teacher</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Class Num</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Receipt</th>";
                                                echo "<th width='10' scope='col'>Date</th>";
                                            echo "</tr>";



if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='checkbox' name='check' id='check' ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='user' id='user' value= " . $row['username'] ." ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='pass' id='pass' value= " . $row['password'] ."  ></td>"; 
                                        ?>        <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='name' id='name' value= "<? echo $row['name']; ?>" ></td>
                                                  <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' value= "<? echo $row['lastname']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='midmark' id='midmark'  value= "<? echo $row['midmark']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='classmark' id='classmark'  value= "<? echo $row['classmark']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='finalmark' id='finalmark'  value= "<? echo $row['finalmark']; ?>"></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='state' id='state' value= "<? echo $row['state']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='level' id='level' value= "<? echo $row['level']; ?>" ></td>
                                                <td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='teacher' id='teacher' value= "<? echo $row['teacher']; ?>" ></td>
                                        <?php   echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='classnum' id='classnum' value= " . $row['classnum'] ." ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='receipt' id='receipt' value= " . $row['receipt'] ." ></td>";
                                                echo "<td align='center'><input class='styled-input' type='text' name='date' id='date' value= " . $row['date'] ." ></td>";      
                                            echo "</tr>";

                                        $_SESSION["suser"]=$row['username'] ;
                                        if(($row['check'])==true)
                                        {$_SESSION["sreceipt"]=$row['receipt'] ;}

                                        }
                                        echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</center>";


}else{
$string = "nothing found !";
$_SESSION["suser"]='';
$_SESSION["sreceipt"]='';
}

echo $string;
}
?>
    <!--row selection -->
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.styled-table').on('change', '.styled-input', function (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
          receiptValue = row.find('input[name=receipt]').val(); 
      alert(receiptValue);

    }
  });
});
</script>.
<!--row selection end -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code should've worked but It didn't and the highlight window is not appearing , is it because of the while loop ?